# How to read Cyrillic Unicode file in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode, locale, getline, cyrillic

I'm trying to read lines from .txt files, that have been saved as Unicode.
That's how i'm doing it:

```
wifstream input;
string path = "test.txt";
input.imbue(locale(input.getloc(),
        new codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, consume_header>));

input.open(path);
if (input.is_open())
{
    wstring line;
    input.seekg( 1 , ios_base::beg);
    getline(input, line);
}
```

It works fine for files with Latin characters. 
But for Cyrillic files I get weird symbols instead of spaces and adjacent characters.

For example:

What is in the input file:

> Госдеп США осудил нападение на

What I get:

> ︓осдепР!ШАР>судилР=ападениеР=а

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: sure it's not an output problem? just because you're reading in unicode doesn't mean you're outputting into a unicode environment.

Comment: I would remove this line: input.imbue(locale(input.getloc(),
        new codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, consume_header>));

Comment: Re "What am I doing wrong?", I feel very much like being glib and answering "Using the C++ standard library", because it should do this by default. It should not be necessary to figure out how to use it for this. Or work around it.

Comment: gkhh... Russian political news made their way to StackOverflow... Noooo...

Comment: oh, maybe open the file in **binary mode**? try that.

Comment: Also note that in Windows, 0x10FFFF won't fit in Windows' 16-bit `wchar_t` that's specified as the `Elem` type. But should be able to use the `char32_t` type.

Comment: @MarcB, it isn't an output problem I see the line in debugger.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, tryed oppening in bunary mode, the same result.

Comment: @duDE, if I remove it, then I need to conver a line somehow.

Comment: @Mints97, so it goes ;)

Comment: Are you sure your input is in UTF16, not in UTF8?

Comment: @Petr, more or less, with codecvt_utf8 I get an empty string.

Comment: @malheur, try looking into input file in binary mode and check that each space occupies two bytes, not one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, figured out the way:

```
FILE *input= _wfopen(L"test.txt", L"rb");
wchar_t line[1000];
test.txtfgetws(line, 1000, input);
```

Works fine like that. Was quite stupid of me not to try it first.
So thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

one line looks very suspicous in your code:

`input.seekg(1, ios_base::beg);`

it sets file position, so reading utf16 string starting position 1 might be incorrect (BOM is read incorrectly). i have the same result for utf16 file in little endian.

so you might change position to 0 or delete this line in order to make this code work

Comment: I added it cos there's a weird character in the beginning of file. It worked fine for Latin files.

Comment: "weird character in the beginning" is BOM i guess